# How to create a "triangle tensor product" symbol

Tags: symbols

In his lecture notes about D-modules, J. Bernstein defines a variant of the tensor product which he denotes as:

[image]

How could I write a "triangle tensor product" like this in latex?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\tritens{\mathbin{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{.3pt}{\triangle}{\scriptstyle\times}
    {O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}
}
\begin{document}
$\dot F \tritens \dot H = \triangle^! (...)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the `\mathbin` spacing is not desired, it can be removed:

```
\newcommand\tritens{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{.3pt}{\triangle}{\scriptstyle\times}
    {O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's incredible! Thank you very much!

Comment: If I get it right, `stackengine` forces to overlay two symbols, one being the triangle, and the other being the cross. But what does `{O}{c}...{L}` do ?

Comment: @sylvainulg You can see the documentation at https://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine.  But, the first argument is the relative vertical shift between the two glyphs, 2nd is the base glyph, 3rd is the overlay, 4th argument is whether the shift is positive for **O**ver or negative for **U**nder shifts, the 5th (l,c or r) is the horizontal alignment of the glyphs, 6th is F when stack is to be output or T if it is to be temporarily withheld, 7th if F if the total width is considered the stack width or T if the base glyph only defines the width, 8th is S for Short stack or L for Long stack (see docs)

Comment: Thanks. `{.3pt}` is the part I had overlooked, and which makes things align.

Answer (score 4):

My guess:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tritensor}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\tritensor@\relax}}
\newcommand{\tritensor@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\triangle$\cr
    \hidewidth\scalebox{0.8}{$\times$}\hidewidth\cr
  }%
}
\makeatother

\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\tritensor\boxtimes$

$\dot{F}\tritensor\dot{H}=\triangle^{!}(\dot{F}\boxtimes\dot{H})$

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative with an equilateral triangle as wide as `\boxtimes`, which distinguishes better between the special tensor product and the triangle operator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@tritensor
\newcommand{\btensor}{\mathbin{\btensor@}}
\newcommand{\btensor@}{%
  \text{%
    \settowidth{\unitlength}{$\m@th\boxtimes$}%
    \linethickness{\fontdimen8\textfont3}%
    \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \roundjoin
    \polygon(0.075,0.03)(0.925,0.03)(0.5,0.733)
    \Line(0.2952,0.4097)(0.6748,0.03)
    \Line(0.7048,0.4097)(0.3252,0.03)
    \end{picture}%
  }%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\dot{F}\btensor\dot{H}=\triangle^{!}(\dot{F}\boxtimes\dot{H})$

$\scriptstyle\dot{F}\btensor\dot{H}=\triangle^{!}(\dot{F}\boxtimes\dot{H})$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `\triangletimes` included in the [`stix` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/stix):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}

$\triangletimes$

\end{document}
```

[image: \triangletimes]

However it's not exactly the symbol you want (the cross is smaller).